# Would you ever pass anything other than (MyClass, self) to super()?

Tags: python, inheritance

I know that in Python 3, you can write `super()` and Python automatically passes the correct arguments to `super`.

It's also possible to introduce subtle bugs by accidentally writing `super(Parent, self)`.

Are there any scenarios where you **wouldn't** want to pass the current class as the first argument to `super`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, potentially you might want to skip the immediate superclass method, but still call the methods further up the hierarchy. This might happen for example when you know you have replaced the logic with your own, and calling the superclass method would be pointless or even harmful.

Comment: Aha, an excellent point. I'd feel obliged to leave an explanatory comment in that situation though.